# Haystack search is not working with autocomplete

Tags: python, django, search-engine, django-haystack, whoosh

I am trying to use django-haystack for search functionality in our product. When user enters a any search keyword(i.e. 'computer'), it should search for this keyword against multiple fields. E.g. when a user enters "Computer" it should find the objects where "Computer" is present in any of the field in that object. But there is a problem. If a user enters only "Comp" into search field, it isn't finding objects at all.

So I have tried to use autocomplete. With autocomplete I was able to achieve this for only one field. For other fields again its failing return result.

I am having haystack with whoosh as backend.

**Environment Detail:

Django v1.5.3 

Haystack v2.1.0 

Whoosh v2.5.3**

Following is defined in my search_index.py file.

```
class Message_Index(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    message = indexes.CharField(model_attr='messagetext', null=True)
    forum = indexes.CharField(model_attr='forum', null=True)
    status = indexes.CharField(model_attr='status', null=True)
    tags = indexes.CharField(model_attr='tags', null=True)
    author_name = indexes.EdgeNgramField(null=True)
    author_number = indexes.EdgeNgramField(null=True)
    message_date = indexes.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Message

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare_author_name(self, obj):
        return obj.message.user.name

    def prepare_author_number(self, obj):
        return obj.message.user.number

    def prepare_message_date(self, obj):
        return obj.message.date

    def prepare_tags(self, obj):
        return [tag.tag for tag in obj.tags.all()]

    def prepare_message_thread(self, obj):
        return obj.message.thread
```

I am trying to search in following way:

when I am trying to search with search_keyword = 'user1', its returning the correct result, but when I am entering search_keyword = '223', its not returning any result.

```
results_by_name = results.autocomplete(author_name=search_keyword)
results_by_number = results.autocomplete(author_number=search_keyword)

if results_by_name.count() > 0:
    combined_resultsets(results,results_by_name,'message_date')
elif results_by_number.count() > 0:
    combined_resultsets(results,results_by_number,'message_date')
```

combined_resultsets is function and defined as below:

```
def combined_resultsets(resultset1, resultset2, sortby):
    if sortby is not None:
        resultset1 = sorted(chain(resultset1, resultset2),key=attrgetter(sortby))
    else:
        resultset1 = chain(resultset1, resultset2)
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

please setting your url project to autocomplete method on view.py application root.
you can follow documentation haystack on [Autocomplete](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autocomplete.html), and please check your template indexes.